# Can't access to /data/user/0 while having root privileges

Tags: android, flutter, dart, root

I'm basically trying to access to /data/user/0 on Android, but it's not working.

My AVD is rooted, and I have granted root privileges thanks to `RootAccess.requestRootAccess`. Also, /data/user/0 have read/write/execute access for all users.

Here's my code (with comments) :

```dart
if (!(await RootAccess.requestRootAccess)) {
 print("You should root your device to make this app working.");
 return;
}

File file = File("/data/user/0/com.bla.bla.bla/afile.txt");
print(file.existsSync()); // will print false whereas this file exists
// I can only have access to 'personnal' files with getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()

// following code won't work : Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Directory listing failed, path = '/data/user/0/' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)
Directory directory = Directory('/data/user/0');
List<FileSystemEntity> fileList = await directory.list().toList();
for (FileSystemEntity file in fileList) {
  if (file is File) {
    print('File: ${file.path}');
  } else if (file is Directory) {
    print('Directory: ${file.path}');
  }
}

// the only thing working is executing bash command from the app, but it's not a viable solution
ProcessResult result = await Process.run('su', ['-c', 'ls -l /data/user/0']);
if (result.exitCode == 0) {
  List<String> fileList = result.stdout.toString().split('\n');
  for (String file in fileList) {
    print('File: $file');
  }
} else {
  print('Error: ${result.stderr}');
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help :)